# how to disable the window maximize icon using PyQt4?

Tags: python, resize, window, pyqt, pyqt4

I would like to know how to disable the window Maximise button in pyqt4. I am at present using QWidget.setFixedSize (self, QSize) to prevent user window resizing, however the maximise button is still enabled and when pressed causes the application to move to the top left corner of the screen. I am basically wanting to replicate the behaviour of the Windows calculator application, where the maximise icon is greyed out. Does anyone know how to achieve this with PyQt4?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Haven't worked with it but research seems to point to messing with the window flags.

[QWidget](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html) has a method called `setWindowFlags`.

[Here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qt-windowflags.html) is the doc for the Qt.WindowFlags class.

[Here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qt.html#WindowType-enum) is a reference for all of the flags. Look for `Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint`

In general it seems like you need to find a way to enable the `Qt.CustomizeWindowHint` flag and disable the `Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint` flag. Either way, you probably want this in addition to `setFixedSize` so that's a good start.

Edit:

Something like

```
win.setWindowFlags(win.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.CustomizeWindowHint)
win.setWindowFlags(win.windowFlags() & ~QtCore.Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint)
```

Assuming your import is something like this

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore
```

This would turn on the `CustomizeWindowHint` flag and turn off the `WindowMaximizeButtonHint` flag, I hope. Let me know if this works at all.

Edit:

As discovered by OP, the only call necessary for his desired outcome:

```
win.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint)
```

but beware, since this will also remove the close button and potentially mess with other window flags.

Comment: Thanks Brian, your research pointed me in the right way. In the end it was simpler than you were thinking. A call to win.setWindowFlags was required however win.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint) did the job. It appears a call to WindowMinimizeButtonHint will disable the window maximize button; and likewise a call to WindowMaximizeButton hint will disable the minimize button

Comment: @jim Glad it helped! Good to know if I decide to start playing with pyqt in the future.

Comment: Note the original answer was the best one, since the one the OP chose also removes the close button and potentially changes the other window flags.

Answer (score 15):

This works perfectly:

```
MainWindow.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint)
```

Comment: Works for PyQt5 as well.

Answer (score 1):

you could set the maximumSize and minimumSize with the same values, it'll get to dissapear maximise button

Answer (score 1):

This helped me:

```
Form.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(width, height))
```

It would go here in your class:

```
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(328, 212)
        Form.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(352, 189))
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in PyQT6:

```
MainWindow.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowType.CustomizeWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowType.WindowCloseButtonHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowType.WindowMinimizeButtonHint)
```

Hope it's useful!