# Remove/Disable Close Button in PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have seen questions asking if they can [remove the maximize button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600081/how-to-disable-the-window-maximize-icon-using-pyqt4), but I want to ask if it is possible to remove/disable the close button?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The answer is the same as the answer in the question you linked to.  Only a slight change is necessary.

```
self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint, False)
```

Comment: I can't get this working. "object has no attribute 'setWindowFlag'"
And if I try to use setWindowFlags, then it will not take two parameters.

Comment: think this should/could work in PySide

Answer (score 6):

The `CustomizeWindowHint` flag needs to be set first before the `WindowCloseButtonHint` flag can be changed.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27496734